# Android GpsStatus.NmeaListener.onNmeaReceived(long timestamp, String nmea) no documentation

Tags: android, gps

what is `timestamp' here. is the the system time in milliseconds since the Epoch? or the GPS time?

I'm seeing the system time, but that might not be consistent.